# Do I need to remove old adhesive residue before installing new self-adhesive flooring?

Tags: flooring

I have an old peel and stick floor in my kitchen that's is getting replaced. I'm putting down a new peel and stick floor. I'm removing the old one because it's curling and lifting from age. The subfloor has the sticky residue in it. Do I need to remove the adhesive or can I lay the floor right on top?

Answer (score 2):

Check the "surface prep" instructions as it will likely instruct you to remove all previous residue, grease, dust, etc... or else they won't warrant their product.

FYI, removing all of the residue is damn near impossible as you are finding out and if you lay down new peel-n-stick then take a wild guess at what will happen to your new flooring in a few years.

I would probably choose to lay down the thinnest underlayment I can find such as [1/4 inch common plywood](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Underlayment-1-4-in-Common-Sumauma-Plywood-Underlayment-Application-as-4-x-8/1000750294) so that the project doesn't go to sh1t after a few years.

Answer (score 1):

First off, check with the manufacturers of the tile you're putting down on surface preparation. In my experience, glues and adhesives don't stick well to old glues and adhesives or to the residue they leave. You should clean the surface with an adhesive remover like Goof Off. You can get it at many home stores. As always, read and follow the directions. Good luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have put down peel n' stick flooring after removing an older peel n' stick floor. You need to lay down a new 1/4" layer on top of the old floor. Yes the new floor would stick to the older sub-floor/glue, however, you'll find edges and corners that just won't stay stuck down. With a new 1/4" floor you'll set. Just pull out the baseboard shoe moulding and reinstall when complete.